# Displaying Latex files on tablets

Tags: equations, conversion, svg, latexit

I need to display short mathematical formulae on mainstream tablets. Presently, I type the equations in LaTeX, convert the LaTeX document to PDF, and then to SVG before displaying it. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this. I presently use LaTeXiT (for Mac) and there are some problems converting it to SVG (pdf2svg path not found), which is why I need to go through the entire process.

Comment: Do these equations form part of something bigger? Like a document? Or just, ... well, LaTeX equations, for fun... you know.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).